# LaTexila gives me blank pages, if I use t1enc or T1 fontenc

Tags: font-encodings

I use LaTeXila on Solus (Linux). Everything works well, but I get the following warning every time:

**Please use \usepackage{t1enc} with \usepackage[magyar]{babel}, to get accented chars hyphenated.**

So, if I try it with t1enc package, I get a totally blank page. And the situation is the same with T1 fontenc.

Is it possible that I don't have any of these packages? Can I install it someway? Or there is other problem?

Here is some code, but the output is the same if it contains anything else.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,headheight=15.1pt,headsep=5mm,top=20mm,bottom=80mm,inner=30mm,outer=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setcounter{page}{63}
\usepackage{t1enc} %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} the output is the same, blank page
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\frenchspacing
\author{László Bence}
\begin{document}
(2) Számítsuk ki az $f(x) = e^{-|x|}/2$ sűrűségfüggvényű változó várható értékét és szórását!

(3) Adjunk példát olyan valószínűségi változóra, melynek a mediánja nem egyezik meg (illetve megegyezik) a várható értékével!

(4) Legyen $\xi$ eloszlásfüggvénye $F(x) = sin(x)$, ha $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2, F(x) = 0,$ ha $x < 0$ és $F(x) = 1$, ha $x > \pi/2$. Számolja ki $\xi$ mediánját és várható értékét!

(5) Legyen $f(x) = 3x^2$, ha $x \in [0,1]$ és $f(x) = 0$ egyébként. Lássuk be, hogy $f$ sűrűségfüggvény. Határozzuk meg a megfelelő eloszlásfüggvényt, mediánt, várható értéket és szórásnégyzetet!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add minimal code showing the issue?

Comment: @egreg Sure. I updated my issue with a short code, but with my full header.

Comment: I have no problem with the code. Note that the warning suggests `t1enc`, which is obsolete; do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead and remove `\usepackage{t1enc}`. Also remove the `dvips` option (irrelevant for the issue, but recommended).

Comment: I replaced t1enc with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} (also removed dvips), but the output is still a blank page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its solved by using a complete tex installation

Comment: @Andew Swann I agree with it. I had a problem with my TeX production system, but not with the typesetting system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed texlive-all and it solved my problem. It seems that texlive-base isn't enough. On Solus, what uses eopkg package manager:
`sudo eopkg install texlive-all`